# How do I plot the transfer function of this formula in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I don't really understand how to plot the transfer function for an arbitrary formula. The Matlab documentation says to get the Bode plot, I'll need to create a transfer function. They give an example using: tf([]) but this only gives third order.

How can I plot the bode plot of my specific formula?

It is:

y = 1./((Z0./Zl).^2 .* j.*sin(B .* d)/2 + exp(j .* B .* d).*(1 + Z0 ./ Zl))

Where Zl, d, and B are a vector of values for each frequency. Here is my full Matlab script.

```
numElem = 200;
w = linspace(2*pi*10^8,2*pi*10^10,numElem);
wRes = 2*pi*10^9;

%%Insert wRes (resonant frequency)
for n = 1:numElem
    if w(n) > wRes 
        w = [w(1:n - 1), wRes, w(n:numElem)];
        resLocation = n;
        break
    end
end

freq = w ./ (2*pi);
lambda =  299792458 ./ freq;

%Beta
B = pi/2 .* w ./wRes;
B(resLocation) = pi/2;

%Distance
d = lambda(resLocation) ./ 4;

Z0 = 50; %Ohms
C = 10^(-12);
L = 1/(wRes^2*C);
Zl = 1 ./ (j .* w .* C + 1 ./ (j .* w .* L));

y = 1./((Z0./Zl).^2 .* j.*sin(B .* d)/2 + exp(j .* B .* d).*(1 + Z0 ./ Zl))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounter with this problem before and it's really simple.
your amplitude is 20log(|data|) and your phase is arctan(real(data)/imag(data)) so you can use this formulas as below:

```
Amplitude=20*log10(abs(y));
phase = angle(y)*180/pi;
subplot(211)
semilogx(freq,Amplitude)
subplot(212)
semilogx(frq,phase)
```

result is:
[image]